# Usar o conteúdo de um campo input numa função JS

Tags: javascript

estou começando agora no JS

Eu tenho um campo input:
`<input required type='date' name="data1" id="data1" class="form-control" />`

Ai eu criei um botão que ao clicar vai pegar o conteúdo desse campo e colocar em outro campo concatenando algumas informações:

`<input type="button" onclick="this.form.introducao.value=form.data1+form.texto">`

Só que antes eu preciso converter essa data1 que está no input no formado 2018-11-01 no formato normal 01/11/2018

Como eu faço isso?

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str="2018-11-01";

var newstr = str.split('-').reverse().join('/');

console.log(newstr);
```

O método `split()` divide um objeto String em um array de strings ao separar a string em substrings

O método `reverse()` inverte os itens de um array. O primeiro elemento do array se torna o último e o último torna-se o primeiro.

O método `join()` junta todos os elementos de uma array em uma string e retorna esta string.

> Se o separador no método `join()` for omitido os elementos do array são separados com uma vírgula (","). Se o separador for uma string vazia, todos os elementos são juntados sem nenhum caractere entre eles

### Sobre seu comentário

```
como eu faço para a data ir parar ai dentro desse parênteses sendo que 
ela está digitada em um input do formulário?
```

Com uma função JavaScript

```js
function myFunction() {
var str=document.getElementById("data1").value;

console.log(str);

var newstr = str.split('-').reverse().join('/');

console.log(newstr);

}
```

```html
<input required type='date' name="data1" id="data1" class="form-control" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

**Com Jquery**

> O evento focusout é acionado assim que o elemento perde o foco

```js
var str = $("#data1");
    str.focusout( function(){
    //data retornada do input
    console.log(str.val());
    //data transformada
    console.log(str.val().split('-').reverse().join('/'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required type='date' name="data1" id="data1" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado pela ajuda, nesse exemplo que você me deu, você escreveu a data dentro do comando ('2018-11-01'), como eu faço para a data ir parar ai dentro desse parênteses sendo que ela está digitada em um input do formulário?

Answer (score 0):

Nesse exemplo basicamente, a data é pega do `input`, é transformada em um Objeto do tipo `Date` e é formatada pegando dia, mês e ano separadamente, após isso concatena com o texto digitado e insere em um `<p>`:

```js
function forData() {
  var data = document.getElementById("data1").value;
  var texto = document.getElementById("texto1").value;

  var d = new Date(data);
  var dataFormatada = (d.getDate() + 1) + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();

  var concatenar = "Data: " + dataFormatada + " Texto: " + texto;

  document.getElementById("inserir").innerText = concatenar;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input required="required" type='date' name="data1" id="data1" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <input required="required" type="text" name="texto1" id="texto1" class="form-control">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="forData()" value="Enviar">
</form>

<p id="inserir"></p>
```